# Unable to find .bashrc or write in bash_profile

Tags: java, bash, macos, terminal, javadoc

I got an [Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nBPB.png)  from my CS class. Apparently, .bashrc doesn't exist in my MacOS. I tried to write in .bash_profile, which displays like this [.bash_profile file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uG82.png) As I copied the lines to the end of the file and typed in command source ~./bashrc, it didn't run obviously. I think it's because I haven't established PATH for Java (also don't know how to do that). I'm really new to this concept so could anyone help me sort this out?

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` (your posted command is a *typo*). And if you put the commands in `~/.bash_profile` you should `source ~/.bash_profile`. But ultimately I question the value of that `alias`, and would suggest you use a proper build tool. Like `maven`.

Comment: If you added the commands to `~/.bash_profile` then your need to run `source ~/.bash_profile` to get them to take effect.  If you don't have a `~/.bashrc` file, you can create it. If your shell is `zsh` (and not `bash`) you can add to (or create) `~/.zprofile` and source that file instead

Comment: It looks like there are spaces around the "=" in the `export PATH` line of your `~/.bash_profile` -- this will not work right (and should print an error). You need to remove the extraneous spaces.

Comment: @Erik : I consider your last suggestion (regarding `.zshrc`) to be a bit dangerous: This would require that the commands inside `~/.bash_profile` are written in a way that they are compatible with bash **and** zsh. While this **can** be done, care has to be taken.